# Java Script Questionnaire Code Improvement

Tags: javascript, onclick, innerhtml

I am working on an assignment that I have submitted recently using Bootstrap 4 (just to make things look pretty) for a Questionnaire.

The assignment requires that I produce vanilla JS.

I got relatively good results for it, however I would like to see if anyone would be able to demonstrate a more efficient way of doing what I did. I'd like to improve the efficiency of my code.

So this is what I did:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Simple Questionarre</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <b class="question">Obama was a president of the US:</b>
    <div>
        <button onclick="correct()" class="btn btn-primary" id="questionOne yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button onclick="incorrect()" class="btn btn-primary" id="questionOne no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <b class="question">Steve Jobs was the inventor of Oracle:</b>
    <div>
        <button onclick="incorrect()" class="btn btn-primary" id="questionTwo yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button onclick="correct()" class="btn btn-primary" id="questionTwo no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <b class="question">The sun is 147 million km from the moon:</b>
    <div>
        <button onclick="correct()" class="btn btn-primary" id="questionThree yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button onclick="incorrect()" class="btn btn-primary" id="questionThree no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <b class="question">Tesla is the brand of a car fueled by Bio Fuel:</b>
    <div>
        <button onclick="incorrect()" class="btn btn-primary" id="questionFour yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button onclick="correct()" class="btn btn-primary" id="questionFour no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <b class="question">In music, the fifth note above the third note is the Major 7th:</b>
    <div>
        <button onclick="correct()" class="btn btn-primary" id="questionFive yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button onclick="incorrect()" class="btn btn-primary" id="questionFive no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        See Results
    </button>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Results</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- Results -->
                    <p>Obama was a president of the US: Yes.</p>
                    <p>You said <span id="q1answer">nothing...</span></p>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Steve Jobs was the inventor of Oracle: No.</p>
                    <p>You said <span id="q2answer">nothing...</span></p>
                    <hr>
                    <p>The sun is 147 million km from the moon: Yes.</p>
                    <p>You said <span id="q3answer">nothing...</span></p>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Tesla is the brand of a car fueled by Bio Fuel: No.</p>
                    <p>You said <span id="q4answer">nothing...</span></p>
                    <hr>
                    <p>In music, the fifth note above the third note is the Major 7th: Yes.</p>
                    <p>You said <span id="q5answer">nothing...</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And aside from bootstrap jQuery, this is the JS I had to produce for the assignment:

```
document.getElementById('questionOne yes').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('q1answer').innerHTML = 'Yes';
};
document.getElementById('questionOne no').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('q1answer').innerHTML = 'No';
};
document.getElementById('questionTwo yes').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('q2answer').innerHTML = 'Yes';
};
document.getElementById('questionTwo no').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('q2answer').innerHTML = 'No';
};
document.getElementById('questionThree yes').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('q3answer').innerHTML = 'Yes';
};
document.getElementById('questionThree no').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('q3answer').innerHTML = 'No';
};
document.getElementById('questionFour yes').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('q4answer').innerHTML = 'Yes';
};
document.getElementById('questionFour no').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('q4answer').innerHTML = 'No';
};
document.getElementById('questionFive yes').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('q5answer').innerHTML = 'Yes';
};
document.getElementById('questionFive no').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('q5answer').innerHTML = 'No';
};
```

As you can see its clunky and long... I would really appreciate any suggestions and examples!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering your question:**
You can put a little bit more markup on the HTML questions such as:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary question" answer-text="yes" answer-id="q1answer" type="button">Yes</button>
```

(and do it for each question appropriately of course)

and on the js part just this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("button.question").forEach(function(questionElement){
    questionElement.onclick = function() {
        var answerElement = document.getElementById(questionElement.getAttribute("answer-id"));

        // Make sure an answer element exists
        if (answerElement) {
            answerElement.innerHTML = questionElement.getAttribute("answer-text");
        }
    };
});
```

**Couple of things:**

1. It's a bed practice the give spaces in element id.
   For example, I would change `questionOne yes` to `question-one-yes`.
2. I would put all the js inside a function that will be called when the window is loaded, and therefore all the elements are rendered for sure.
   i.e. `window.onload = function(){/*put your js code here*/}`
3. No need to put `onclick=correct()` in the button elements if there is no such a function

Comment: I understand how you use elements to retrieve the answer, which I like. Though now that you have the answer, how would you go about applying that answer to the correct tag in the modal?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question. 'answer-id' attribute holds the id of the element that will hold the answer. The question holds the id of the answer. When an onclick occurs the id is extracted and used to find the answer element.